# window.open doesn't show specified path

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button called "Generate Schedule", when I click this button it will run a method called "schedule()" in a class, and this method will internally run another method called "display()" in another class. The method "display()" will produce an html file as the output which then must be open in a new window to show the results. 
How can I make the window pop with the html file content after clicking on the button?

Here is a part of the code in a jsp file

```
<% FYPScheduler f = new FYPScheduler(); %>
<script type="text/javascript">
.......
function callSchedule()
{

    <%
        f.schedule();
    %>
    window.open("file:///Users/nonya_000/Documents/SeniorProject (1)/SeniorProject/schedule.html");
}
.......
</script>
.......
<button name="ThisButton" onclick="callSchedule()"> Generate Schedule </button>
```

I tried to use window.open(), when I click the button a new window pops but it's empty. Help?

Comment: If you right click in the popup and go to the properties, what url is it loading?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your URL reference is correct - open up a browser and try to go to file:///Users/nonya_000/Documents/SeniorProject (1)/SeniorProject/schedule.html as you have referenced...if its a blank page, you know the problemlies in your schedule.html file or your url reference to that file is incorrect.